# Why won't Cordova work?

Tags: cordova

I'm new to Cordova and it's the first time I've installed it on my PC; I have all the software installed, but when I write `cordova` at the command prompt this happens:

```
$c:\cordova
$c:\
```

Cordova does nothing.

I installed Cordova with this command `npm install -g cordova`. I have Windows 7.

Software I have installed:

- Node.js
- Apache Ant
- Java JDK 1.7

And I set the global `JAVA_HOME`, `ANT_HOME`, `ANDROID` variables.

Comment: You need to create a variable with the name `ANDROID_HOME` not `ANDROID`. Also show what is written in the variable `JAVA_HOME`, `ANT_HOME` and `ANDROID`

Comment: if you write command cordova --version, does it display something?

Comment: yes i have that environments, no Jose Rojas nothing